# Spring SpEL escape package name in T() function

Tags: spring, spring-el

I have simple question, Is it possible to escape package name in Spring-EL function `T(..)`?

The reason why I need this is because I live in Lithuania and all our packages start with country code `lt` f.e. `lt.aaa.bbb.ccc`. As you could expect this something we can not change.

Now, when I try to use SpEL to access some constant or static function in my classes I write:

 `#{T(lt.aaa.bbb.ccc).CONSTANR_VAR}`, but this doesn't work, because SpEL parses expression and interprets `lt` as 'Less Then' not as part of package. This should be a problem for country codes `gt`, `eq` etc.

Is there any way around this, or are we just wery unlucky?

Answer (score 0):

I can't immediately think of a workaround. I created:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10942

against the spring framework to cover the problem. I have SpEL open up at the moment as I'm working on something so I might try to get this fixed soon.